# Scheduler Module throwing "max pool size was reached"

Tags: mysql, asp.net, connection-string, scheduler

Our application hosts a scheduler which pings the database every 30 seconds for available tasks to run. But after two hours of running it starts giving connection pool exhausting error. We have checked that we have Closed / Put all connections used for Mysql.

- Application Connection Pool Size = 200
- Server Max_Connection Param = 1000
- **Connection String**  Server=localhost;Database=mydb;Uid=test;Pwd=test;Minimum Pool
  Size=10;Maximum Pool Size=200;ConnectionLifeTime=100;
  DefaultCommandTimeout=0;Connection Timeout=10;Allow User
  Variables=true;

---

```
9/26/2017 12:00:14 AM:MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): error connecting: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
   at com.ivp.rad.dal.RMYSQLDBProvider.GetConnection(String connectionString)
HResultDAL -> 0
Message -> error connecting: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.
ExceptionSource -> MySql.Data
MachineName -> VM-asdf
CustomMessage -> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): error connecting: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.
```

Comment: Can you verify your MySQL Server is also in the opinion you are closing /putting connections gracefully?

Comment: @Fildor Mysql Server "Show Processlist;" Command shows number of active rows always less than 30.